# Child component not receiving broadcast from parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components, angular-broadcast

I'm building a simple grid component with Angular 1.5 `component`. The structure is:

```
<grid-component>
    <grid-header>
        <grid-cell key="one">Column One</grid-cell>
        <grid-cell key="two">Column Two</grid-cell>
        <grid-cell key="three">Column Three</grid-cell>
    </grid-header>
    <grid-row ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items" model="items">
        <grid-cell key="one">{{ items.one }}</grid-cell>
        <grid-cell key="two">{{ items.two }}</grid-cell>
        <grid-cell key="three">{{ items.three }}</grid-cell>
    </grid-row>
</grid-component>
```

The `<grid-component>` broadcasts an event to `<grid-header>`, but the header component is not receiving the message.

Here is a simple example of my usage.

```
app
.component('gridComponent', {
    controller: function($scope) {
        this.$onInit = function() {
            resource.getItems()
                .then(function(items) {
                    $scope.broadcast('update', items);
                }); 
        };
    }
})
.component('gridHeader', {
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.on('update', function(event, items) {
            controller.items = items;
        });
    }
});
```

The interesting thing is that when I inspect the scopes, they are actually siblings in the scope hierarchy.

**Parent**

```
{
    childHead: null,
    $$childTail: null,
    $$destroyed: false,
    $$isolateBindings: Object,
    $$listenerCount: Object,
    $$listeners: Object,
    $$nextSibling: null,
    $$phase: null,
    $$prevSibling: null,
    $$watchers: null,
    $$watchersCount: 0,
    $ctrl:module.exports.controller,
    $id: 80,
    $parent: {
        $$ChildScope: null,
        $$childHead: h,
        $$childTail: h,
        $$listenerCount: Object,
        $$listeners: Object,
        $$nextSibling: null,
        $$prevSibling: null,
        $$transcluded: true,
        $$watchers: Array[4],
        $$watchersCount: 4,
        $id: 79,    <---
        $parent: {}
    }
}
```

**Child**

```
{
    childHead: null,
    $$childTail: null,
    $$destroyed: false,
    $$isolateBindings: Object,
    $$listenerCount: Object,
    $$listeners: Object,
    $$nextSibling: null,
    $$phase: null,
    $$prevSibling: { parentObject }, <---
    $$watchers: null,
    $$watchersCount: 0,
    $ctrl:module.exports.controller,
    $id: 91,
    $parent: {
        $$ChildScope: null,
        $$childHead: h,
        $$childTail: h,
        $$listenerCount: Object,
        $$listeners: Object,
        $$nextSibling: null,
        $$prevSibling: null,
        $$transcluded: true,
        $$watchers: Array[4],
        $$watchersCount: 4,
        $id: 79, <---
        $parent: {}
    }
}
```

Note id of the parent for both are the same. Also, note that the prevSibling of the child is the parent.

If I change `$scope.$broadcast` to `$scope.$parent.$broadcast` it works as expected because they are siblings.

Why does Angular see these as siblings when they're nested components, and is there a way to broadcast events without having to walk the `$parent` chain?

Comment: why are you using an event in the first place and not using bindings?

Comment: Your question does not answer my question, but in regards to your question: The grid component pulls persisted preferences from a service. This needs to happen internal to the component, not in the page controller. The grid needs to communicate these to to the grid header and rows. The header and rows are not declared inside the grid template but are declared with the grid is in the page.

Comment: bindings have nothing to do with page...but with parent. Also that same service can be shared across any part of the app.

Comment: Then please elaborate on what you mean by using bindings instead of events. Do you have a resource or example?

Comment: yes... angular component docs

Comment: Wel! Thanks for not being helpful.

Comment: why is that not helpful? The concept is explained, along with code explanation , and there are examples there

Comment: It's not helpful because it doesn't answer my question. Even if there is a better way of implementing my example, I'm looking for a better understanding of eventing with hierarchical components in Angular 1.5.

Comment: events are typically a last resort . Did you try using the normal and most common approach with bindings? Create a demo also for this that replicates problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125133/discussion-between-smalone-and-charlietfl).